# add to the right click context menu so right click folder can choose to run a batch file passing the path of the folder as a parameter to the program

Tags: batch-file, context-menu

How do you get add an item to the right click context menu, so when you right click a folder you can choose to run a batch file passing the path of the folder as a parameter to the program.

I have hearing problems, so I always download a movie with its Subs. The srt file must be changed to the same name as the movie name, e.g. In the movie folder will be 2 files:

Spiderman.2022. 1080p.BluRay.H264.AAC-RARBG.mp4
English.srt
English.srt must become -> Spiderman.2022. 1080p.BluRay.H264.AAC-RARBG.srt

I have a batch file that when run from the same folder changes a srt to the same name as any video in the same folder

Here is the srt.bat script:

```
for  %%i  in (*.mp4 *.avi *.mpg *.flv *.mkv)  do  rename  *.srt  "%%~ni.srt"
```

I would like to not have to copy the srt.bat file manually into the folder and execute and then delete it. Rather, I would like to be able to right click on the folder or in a blank spot in the folder and have a shortcut to automate this process I do so often. I placed the batch file for storage and execution here:

C:\Console\srt.bat
I did some digging and found this:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Rename subtitles file]
@="Rename subtitles file in folder"
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Rename subtitles file\command]
@="C:\\Console\\srt.bat -d \"\"%V\"\""
```

It adds a right button shortcut called Rename subtitles file in folder which executes srt.bat.

When I right click on a space in the required folder and choose the console2 shortcut, I see the black window open up very briefly and execute, but the name of the video file remains unchanged. I think it runs the srt.bat but the effect is not directed at the open folder.

How do I correct this?

Any other ideas on how to achieve my desired effect would also be appreciated.

Please note: I am not a coder, so please be a literal as possible i.e. write the code exactly as needed in this situation. I have no idea what the code on this page means, I just spent a few hours reading and then copy and pasted.

***This is the working solution, Thanks to Mofi @stackoverflow.com:***

working reg file looks like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Rename subtitles file]
@="Rename subtitles file in folder"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Rename subtitles file\command]
@="cmd.exe /D /C C:\\Console\\srt.bat \"%V\""
```

For working srt.bat file like this:

```
for %%i in ("%~1\*.mp4" "%~1\*.avi" "%~1\*.mpg" "%~1\*.flv" "%~1\*.mkv") do rename "%~1\*.srt" "%%~ni.srt"
```

Many thanks to Mofi for your patience and kindness of your time and knowledge!!

Comment: "write the code exactly as needed in this situation" .. SU is not a script writing service.  Perhaps someone will choose to help you out anyway.